# Display certain arraylist, with click on certain button

Tags: java, android, listview, button, arraylist

My xml has several buttons how do I when I click on a particular button load an arraylist in the listview

example

```
Button1 clicked -> arraylist <Questions> loads in listview1
Button2 clicked -> arraylist <Replies> loads in listview1
Button3 clicked -> arraylist <Null> loads in listview1
```

using the same listview, I'm currently doing this with several activitys created one for each button I think this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to to do something when you press a button you need to add an `OnClickListener` to each of your buttons.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
            ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
            // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
            // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your 
           // array as a third parameter.
           ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             your_array_list );

             lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you works perfectly, the source of the item is very weak you would know why? follows a print of how it is getting http://prntscr.com/id0x84 http://prntscr.com/id0xgx